# SQL Server Express Default Protocols Set On Installation

Tags: sql-server-2008

Are named pipes and TCP/IP disabled by default, when SQL Server Express 2008 is installed? I am trying to figure out if these two protocols being disabled was an act of installation or subsequent configuration. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

default install of SQL server express only allow local connections with no network enabled. So tcp/ip is disabled by default, and you have to enable it manually.

Named pipes should be enabled by default though.